# How can I do it smarter?

Tags: c

I must read and extract some values from string.
These values are coded like this:

```
k="11,3,1" v="140.3"
```

I have defined the codes and created struct with all field as well as a temp one where I store k and v. In `fillFields` proc I transfer values from temp struct to the right one (with the valid types).
It works but I have many fields and  `fillFields` would need to have many `if-conditions`. Maybe  someone could give me any hint how to write it smarter.

The simplified code now:

```
   #define ASK                       "11,3,1"
   #define BID                       "11,2,1"
   #define CLOSE                     "3,1,1"


    typedef struct tic {

      float ask;
      float bid;
      float close;
    }tic, *ticP;
    typedef struct pElem {
      char       * k;
      char       * v;
    }pElem, *pElemP;

    void fillFields(ticP t, pElemP p)
    {
      if (strcmp( ASK, p->k)==0)
      {
        printf ("ASK %s\n", p->v);
        t->ask = atof(p->v);
      }
      if (strcmp( BID, p->k)==0)
      {
        printf ("BID %s\n", p->v);
        t->bid = atof(p->v);
      }
      if (strcmp( CLOSE, p->k)==0)
      {
        printf("CLOSE >>>%s<<<\n", p->v)    ;
        t->close =  atof (p->v);
      }
    }
```

Comment: The definition of "smarter code" is quite varied and often controversial ;-)

Comment: Questions about working code belong on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: This should go on a codereview site.

Comment: you could use "else"! if it is "ASK" you remove the comparison with BID and CLOSE.

Comment: Look at yacc(1), this can simplify the parsing code greatly.

Comment: [Flex + Bison](https://www.google.com/search?name=f&hl=en&q=Flex+%2B+Bison). Smartest ones =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than save the text value in `pElem`, save the converted values.

This creates an extra step in parsing `k="11,3,1" v="140.3"`, to convert text to an enumerated type, but it's paid once.  The `fillFields()` calls then run simpler.  Assuming you have more `ticP` variables, it's a win.

```
typedef enum pElem_type {
  pElem_None, pElem_ASK, pElem_BID, pElem_CLOSE, pElem_N
} pElem_type;

typedef struct pElem {
  pElem_type type;
  float value;
} pElem;

void fillFields(ticP t, const pElem *p) {
  switch (p->type) {
  case pElem_ASK:
    printf("ASK %f\n", p->value);
    t->ask = p->value;
    break;
  case pElem_BID:
    printf("BID %f\n", p->value);
    t->bid = p->value;
    break;
  case pElem_CLOSE:
    printf("Close %f\n", p->value);
    t->close = p->value;
    break;
  default:
    printf("Error\n");
  }
}


// Further simplifications possible
typedef struct tic {
  float field[pElem_N];
}tic, *ticP;

static const char *FieldName[pElem_N] = {
  "None", "ASK", "BID", "Close"
};

void fillFields(ticP t, const pElem *p) {
  if (p->type < pElem_N) {
    printf("%s %f\n", FieldName[p->type], p->value);
    t->field[p->type] = p->value;
  }
}
```

Comment: The code, which I have attached was simplified. But tic struct has many field and not every field is of type float.

Comment: @MaMu  Same approach if your fields have different types.  I assuming there are not _lots_ of different types, but _lots_ of fields.  After string-to-enumeration, use that enumeration to parse the value per the type that goes with the enumeration value.  There are many aspects of your task not posted (e.g. "not every field has type float") and that steers further suggestions, but the gist is that to collapse similar coding where possible.  Enumerated types help a lot.